# C++ String to String Conversion

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, initialization

```
char ch[3];
strcpy(ch,"Hello");
cout<<ch<<" "<<sizeof(ch);
```

Q1. Why is it printing "Hello" when the size of ch is 3 ?

Q2. If ch is converted from ch[2] to ch[6] (by Implicit Type Conversion) then why is sizeof(ch) still 3 ?

Comment: what is ch? I only see `char a[3]`

Comment: A1: Undefined Behavior; A2: Its type is not being converted at all.

Comment: It looks like there is some mistake int the code, you use char a[3] then copy it to "ch" instead of "a".

Comment: You could corrupt other things in memory if you continue this way.

Comment: Dangerous things you're doing there... Also mandatory suggetsion to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) in c++

Answer (score 3):

strcpy does not do a size check, so it simply writes "Hello\0" at memory address of a, overwriting whatever is located after a in memory.

There are no conversions performed, ch is char[3] as it was before strcpy.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming when you typed `char a[3];` you meant `char ch[3];`.

A1: When you declare an array of some size, it's up to *you* to not exceed it. If you do exceed it as in this case, you get undefined results.

A2: You cannot convert it like this so it's a non-issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing something really dangerous there. This is one of the reasons to use `std::string` you don't have to check if you go out of bounds for simple copying.

**Question 1:**
Like others said already, it printing out "Hello" is undefined behavior and anything can happen. But that's not all. Writing out of bounds like you do in your code is dangerous. You basically got a [Buffer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), if you look at the example on Wikipedia you'll see that it's nearly the same code you got.

**Question 2:**
There is no conversion. When you call `strcpy(ch, "Hello");` your array `ch` [decays into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). There is no way for `strcpy` to know how many chars it can safely copy there, since a pointer is nothing more than a memory address. It doesn't know how much memory is available at the location so simply writes everything even if (like in your case) you go out of bounds.

Things like you got in your code is one of the reasons why pointers are being called unsafe.